# Cannot load file when browsing website from a computer different from the server

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, gac

I have an application running on IIS 7. If I remote desktop to the server I can browse the application just fine

If I try to browse it from my local computer, I get an error:

```
Could not load file or assembly .... or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I added the assembly to the bin folder and the GAC but no luck.

How can it be possible? If I can browse the website on the server, I shouldn't be getting a "dll cannot be found" error.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Smells as a permission problem

Comment: A web app does not rely on the content of a client GAC, unless it's using 3rd party components that require a specific runtime to be installed (e.g. Crystal Reports). Are you using any 3rd party controls or plug-ins? What is the system architecture like? Also, what user is the Application Pool running under?

Comment: I would double check that you are in fact hitting the same server from your remote desktop an local machine.

Comment: @Strillo, it is in fact the CrystalDecisions.Web the dll. One particular thing is that I installed the 3.1 Business Objects SDK on the server, but this dlls doesnt exist on this sdk so I had to register the previous version (11.5) manually. Inetinfo.exe is running under the SYSTEM account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the offending dll is CrystalDecisions.Web then you need to install the redistributable runtime on the client. Check the right versions on SAP (or [Business Objects](http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp)) website or [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1676707.aspx/1) or [here](http://koenwillemse.wordpress.com/2011/02/08/crystal-reports-runtime-for-net-4-0/)